# Ansible Playbook for check if ansible is installed in my localhost

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible

new to ansible but I'm still confused on how to start. I have no idea if I should run a command in my task or there is other approach in checking if the app is installed

Comment: I'd recommend to rephrase question. It is not clear what is the task you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

There are few commands to check if ansible is installed on the host.

```
ansible-playbook --version
```

```
ansible --version
```